# Convert a form into 2 / 3 sections and keep the form validation?

Tags: jquery, forms, multipage

I have a form with 20+ fields and now I am bound to an iframe and i need to separate the form into more sections. How can I best do this and still keep the validation?

I am trying to keep it simple and was thinking to have 3 divs, each holding 7 form fields and the submit button in the last section. But how can i browse the sections and have the validation per section working?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would to be to put the form sections in separate divs, and don't "navigate" with your browser to the separate form parts, but rather use jQuery to navigate the divs.

```
<form>
<div id="form1"><a href="#">form elements 1</a></div>
<div id="form2" style="display:none"><a href="#">form elements 2</a></div>
<div id="form3" style="display:none"><a href="#">for elements 3</a></div>
</form>

<script>
jQuery("a").click( function(){
    jQuery(this).parents("form:first").children("div").hide();
    jQuery(this).parent().show();
});
</script>
```

And have your submit button in the last div.

This will allow you to validate the fields with javascript and show them a div with errors on it.

Comment: With @Senica's answer in mind, you might want to take a look at jQuery UI tabs as well.